# How to retrieve data from SQL Server using pyodbc and Python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement that retrieve data from SQL Server using pyodbc package.

The problem is that the query doesn't return all the data instead it return several records.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [first] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [last] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [Rating] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_t1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data:

[image]

SQL statement:

```
advanced_search_term_list =[]
     sql = (
             r"select ID, first, last, Rating "
             r"from dbo.t3 "
             r"where "
             r"(first LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR ? IS NULL) AND "
             r"(last LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR ? IS NULL) AND "
             r"(Rating = ? OR ? IS NULL)"   
          )       
    param1 = advanced_search_term_list[0]
    param2 = advanced_search_term_list[1]
    param3 = advanced_search_term_list[2]
    rows = cursor.execute(sql, [param1, param1, param2, param2, param3, param3]).fetchall()
    
    for row in rows:
              print(row.ID)
              print(row.first)
              print(row.last)
              print(row.Rating)
```

If the user runs this SQL statement without any user input, the expected output is all the rows.

But instead, it returns these rows only:

[image]

Comment: This looks like you aren't sending `NULL` values. For example looks like for the value of `param3` you're passing `0`.

Comment: ok so why it return these records only ??
i was expect either return all the records or return nothing at all

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK sorry for this i will try to fix it

Comment: What are the *actual* values of your parameters above when the user doesn't input anything? Remember `''` and `0` are both **not** `NULL`. I suspect that what you are actually passing isn't `NULL` (or `None` in Python) but `''`, `''` and `0` respectively.

Comment: ok this was the problem you were right ... But how to show all the data if the user doesn't input anything ... let say for the param3 if the some records have a value other than 0

Comment: Like i mentioned, you need to actually pass `NULL` values, which in Python is `None`. Presumably you'll want to use some `If` statements to assign `None` to the parameter is it has the value `''` or `0` in your Python. My python is rusty, but something like `If param1 == '': param1 = None Else: Param1 = advanced_search_term_list[0]` (Pretty sure there need to be line breaks and white space in there.)

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments of @Larnu i edit the sql statement by adding for the **Rating** field **parameter = 0** like the below line :

```
r"(Rating = ? OR ? IS NULL OR ? = 0)"
```